# Search a field based on two or more columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I want to output the `professor` field based on the input in the yellow fields. The input will be the possible `sub_code` of `column D` OR `column G`. I've tried `VLOOKUP(...)` and `INDEX(...,MATCH(...))`, but I get stuck when trying to perform: `either column D or column G`.

For example, I want `John` to be printed in E7 when I type `Ag1` or `Ps1` in E8.

How could I write a function for this case?

[image: Spreadsheet table]

Comment: @fixer1234 basically, I want `John` to be printed in the yellow cursor box when I type `Ag1` or `Ps1` in that box. I am not sure which formula to use.

Comment: Just to clarify, is it a requirement that the input and result be in the same box?  If so, you would need VBA, because typed input would replace any function in the cell.

Comment: @fixer1234 sorry, it's different box. No need to use the same box. let's say output it in the gray box when I enter `sub_code` in the yellow cursor box.

Comment: Any possibility for more than one professor to have the same Sub_code?

Comment: @fixer1234 one professor can have one or more `sub_code`, but no same `sub_code`. Each `sub_code` is unique.

Comment: Actually, my question was more could both John and Phillip have a same sub_code.

Comment: @fixer1234 No, they cannot have the same `sub_code`.

Comment: Glad to help you @Sokunthaneth ,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

*To Solve the issue you need one **HELPER Cell** to set choice that which Code you want to use.*

[image]

Write this Formula in cell `F10`.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A$6,IF($C$9=1,MATCH($D$10,$D$3:$D$6,0),IF($C$9=2,MATCH($D$10,$G$3:$G$6,0)))),"Wrong Code")
```

**How it works:**

- In Helper Cell `C9`, write your Choice should either 1 or 2.
- Write `Sub Code` in Cell `D10`.
- Formula will search `Sub Code` in `Column D` if `C9 has 1`, otherwise check the `Sub Code` in `Column G.`
- If you set wrong combination in Cells `C9` & `D10` then the Formula will return **Wrong Code** error.

**Edited:**

**Option 2:**

*This Array Formula also can be used in Cell `F10`.*

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A$6,MATCH(1,($D$3:$D$6=$D$10)+($G$3:$G$6=$D$10),0)),"Wrong Code")}
```

**Note,**

- Finish the above written Formula with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.
- While working with **OPTION 2** *no need to write Value in Helper Cell `C9`, only write `Sub Code` in Cell `D10`.*

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: I think the OP's problem is that the Sub_code could be in either column, and you don't know which.  So the task is to just look for it in multiple columns (rather than manually try each column until you find the match).

Comment: @fixer1234, now I've edited the post and included an Array Formula will search Sub Code in both Columns automatically! ☺

Comment: Option 2:much better!  :-)  The examples don't have row or column references, so a little hard to follow.  Should probably also mention that it's case sensitive, and add a couple of sentences explaining how it works.  +1  (And just  delete option 1 so this goes right to the solution.)

Comment: @fixer1234,, Formula doesn't minds Case since considers both Upper & Lower,, 1 is for Ture which so ever in Col D or G .

Comment: In LO Calc, it didn't match unless the case matched.  Guess we found another example where Excel and Calc differ.  In my solution, match worked for either case.  Yours uses an equality, and Calc required matching case for that.

Answer (score 0):

VLOOKUP requires searching the leftmost column, so that won't work.  INDEX + MATCH will work, but MATCH can't search multiple, or two-dimensional, ranges.  A workaround is to combine multiple MATCHes for the different ranges.

[image]

The lookup result in E7 uses this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A2:A5,IFERROR(MATCH(E8,D2:D5,0),0)+IFERROR(MATCH(E8,G2:G5,0),0)),"Invalid Sub_code")
```

Each column has its own MATCH.  The match will occur in only one column, so the IFERROR returns zero if the column doesn't have a match.  Then adding the match values will combine a location index for the column with the match and zero for any additional searched columns.  The question title says "two or more columns".  This is expandable by just adding another MATCH expression for each additional column.

INDEX is wrapped with its own IFERROR in case a bad Sub_code is entered.  MATCH is not case-sensitive, so it will still find a match if only the capitalization isn't the same.

Of course, you can have multiple entry cells and corresponding results cells.

**Alternative**

@Rajesh S noticed that this can also be restructured:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A2:A5,MATCH(E8,D2:D5,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(A2:A5,MATCH(E8,G2:G5,0)),"Invalid Sub_code"))
```

This uses each MATCH expression with INDEX.  The IFERROR on the INDEX takes care of any MATCH errors as well.  The IFERRORS are then nested, so an error in the first lookup goes to the second, and an error there goes to the bad Sub_code warning.  It ends up the same length because while the IFERROR function count decreases, the INDEX function count increases.  This can be scaled up for additional columns by additional nesting.

Use whichever version seems most intuitive.

For comparison of the structure and logic, I'll break the formulas down.

Alternative 1:

```
=IFERROR(
       INDEX(A2:A5,
                 IFERROR( MATCH(E8,D2:D5,0) ,0) + IFERROR( MATCH(E8,G2:G5,0) ,0) )
        ,"Invalid Sub_code")
```

Alternative 2:

```
=IFERROR( 
         INDEX(A2:A5, MATCH(E8,D2:D5,0) )
         ,IFERROR(
                  INDEX(A2:A5, MATCH(E8,G2:G5,0) )
                  ,"Invalid Sub_code")  )
```

Answer (score 0):

`=IFERROR(INDIRECT("A"&IF(SUMPRODUCT(--($D$2:$D$5=$E$8),ROW($A$2:$A$5))=0, SUMPRODUCT(--($G$2:$G$5=$E$8),ROW($A$2:$A$5)), SUMPRODUCT(--($D$2:$D$5=$E$8),ROW($A$2:$A$5)))), IF(E8="","","Invalid code"))`

I admit, it's not the shortest, but in my opinion it's the most stable. Fixer1234 admits his is not too elegant, while Rajesh uses helper cells, which are not best practise as Excel was not designed for them, and could lead to circular references when you get onto more complex projects.

However, back to my formula.

### How it works

`SUMPRODUCT(--($D$2:$D$5=$E$8),ROW($A$2:$A$5)`*: Checks if column D contains a match. If so, it returns the row number of the match. If no match is found, it returns 0.*

`SUMPRODUCT(--($G$2:$G$5=$E$8),ROW($A$2:$A$5)`*: Checks if column G contains a match. If so, it returns the row number of the match. If no match is found, it returns 0.*

`IF(...=0, ..., ...)`*: Checks if the search through column D returned 0, i.e no match. In this case, it returns the result for column G. Otherwise, it just returns the result of column D.*

`INDIRECT("A"&...)`*: The row number from the* `SUMPRODUCT`*s (or the 0, if no match) is combined with "A" - the letter of the first column. The* `INDIRECT` *function then finds the cell with that reference. E.g. it could find the cell called 'A3', or, if no match was found, 'A0' - a non-existent cell.*

`IFERR(..., ...)`*: Checks for and handles errors. If column D contains no match, then it will return the search for column G. However, if column G doesn't contain anything either, then "A0" will just be passed to the* `INDIRECT` *function, which is not a real cell. Therefore, it will result in an error, and it will run the error handler instead of showing the error.*

`IF(E8="","","Invalid code"))`*: Handles the error. If the input cell is blank, it just remains blank as well, as there is no need to make a fuss. However, if it is not blank, but there still is an error, it returns* 'Invalid Code' *, as it can only mean that something was entered, and that that something was invalid.*

### Examples

**Functionally:**

[image: 'He1' is written in E8, E7 returns 'Phillip'.]

[image: 'Kh1' is written in E8, E7 returns 'Deav'.]

**Empty input:**

[image: Both E7 and E8 are empty]

**Invalid input:**

[image: 'Rn1' is written in E8, E7 returns 'Invalid code']

Comment: This works, and demonstrates another approach, but I think it's just more convoluted rather than being more elegant or stable.  It also isn't cleanly scalable if the OP needs to add additional sets of columns (the title says "two or more columns", so this is anticipated).  The formula is twice as long and I'm missing what advantage it has.  But it's a valid approach and the answer is very well written; you did a good job of explaining how it works.